# How to manually find ARMA-GARCH residuals in R?

Tags: regression, arima, residuals, garch

Let's say the data input is called `data`, which is in the form of a financial time series that will be fitted into an ARMA-GARCH model. The GARCH(1,1) is used because it is the best fit for a financial time series with volatility and heteroscedasticity.

Using `ugarchfit` and `ugarchspec` (comparing the BIC values) I found that the best fit is ARMA(2,1)GARCH(1,1) with parameters

`mu = -0.322925157,ar1= 1.904752272, ar2= -0.918770379, ma1=-0.924142232,
  omega= 0.004355971, alpha1= 0.198723766,shape= 6.520216307,                                  beta1 =0.713514758`

Another method of fitting was to look at the acf and pacf of the data and instinctively find a good match, which is ARMA(1,0)GARCH(1,1) with parameters

`mu = -0.453529886,ar1= 0.933776546, omega= 0.006608471, alpha1= 0.257053963,shape=  6.533376243, beta1 =0.622149898`

I'm wondering how can I achieve the residuals from fitting `data` to each of these models and parameters. I tried using `ugarchpath` to input the parameters and each time I generate it comes up with a different model.

So, what I'm asking is what code or function can I use to find the residual manually? Because with the function `resid`, it gives the result from the first model ARMA(2,1)GARCH(1,1) because of the lowest BIC value. How can I get it from the ARMA(1,0)GARCH(1,1)?

Comment: There are two kinds of residuals, standardized and nonstandardized. If `resid` does not give you the ones you want, perhaps there is an option in the function allowing to choose between the two and you can adjust it? Alternatively, look at the slots of the fitted model, residuals must be hiding in there (`resid` only extracts them from there). Use `slotNames` to learn what slots there are in the fitted model object. Within the specific slots, use `names` to learn what is in them.